# How to rename a new google sheet using cell references?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, data-science

So currently, I am trying to make a google script that exports separate google sheets for each unique username -- i.e., to try to make a customizable report for each client. Basically, I have a list of unique usernames -- a list called uniqueUserName -- and I want to set the name of the new sheet to the "Name" which corresponds to the username. For example, suppose Sally1  is in the following table. The code would search through the usernames (with a for loop) and, once the for loop hits Sally1, the code would return Sally Wall -- i.e., the name corresponding to her username. Sally Wall would then be the new name of the document.

| Username | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Timmy | Tim Jones |
| Sally1 | Sally Wall |
| catsforlife | John Mueller |
| ready2learn | Cindy Rodney |

I have tried the following code:

```
newSheet.setName(function(uniqueName, values){
   for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0].Username === uniqueName) {
         return values[i][1].Name;
         break;
      }
   }
});
```

(I include the break function, because, if someone's name shows up twice, I don't want to copy their name twice. )

How would I have to adjust this code to serve these ends? Is this on the right track?

Honestly, I've been at this code for a while, looking up as much as I can, on stack overflow, YouTube, so your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, when you said "a google script that exports separate google sheets for each unique username" do you mean that you're using the makeCopy() method to export separate copies of the google sheet file with unique file names based on the usernames? Can you also share the complete code just to make sure we know the whole logic and to reduce any assumptions on our end?

Comment: Values and uniqueName are undefined or atleast we don't know where the come from and your code doesn't actual set a sheet name so we probably need to see the the code that calls this function  in order to get an understanding of what your attempting to accomplish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you're passing a function to the [setName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename) method, but it expects a string. One straightforward way to solve this would be to immediately call the function after it's declared, passing the arguments as well.

Another thing is that you're trying to access the properties `Name` and `Username` of elements in `values`, but, assuming you received `values` from [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), those properties don't exist. You can get the values you want by just using the indices, as you're already doing: `values[i][0]` and `values[i][1]`.

Also, you don't need to use `break` because the loop will be interrupted by the `return` statement anyway.

Considering the above and assuming there's a sheet called *Names* (that has the names you posted) and another called *Report Template*, you can change your code to something like:

```
function newNamedSheetTest() {
  const uniqueName = 'Sally1';
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const values = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Names').getDataRange().getValues();
  const newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report Template').copyTo(spreadsheet);

  newSheet.setName(function (uniqueName, values) {
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if (values[i][0] === uniqueName) {
        return values[i][1];
      }
    }
  }(uniqueName, values));
}
```

Another option would be to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the name of the sheet:

```
function newNamedSheetTestShort() {
  const uniqueName = 'Sally1';
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const values = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Names').getDataRange().getValues();
  const newSheetName = values.filter(row => row[0] === uniqueName).map(row => row[1]);
  const newSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report Template').copyTo(spreadsheet);
  newSheet.setName(newSheetName);
}
```